# LookupPrivilegeName returns same privelege names for different luid

Tags: c++, winapi

My code:

```
VOID CheckWindowsPrivileges(DWORD PID)
{
HANDLE hProcess;
HANDLE hToken;

    // Get Process Handle with QUERY_INFORMATION rights
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, PID);
    // Get Access Token with READ rights
    OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &hToken);
    
    // Get the size of TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure and write it in bufSize
    DWORD bufSize = 0;
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, 0, &bufSize);
    
    // Allocate the space for TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure in heap
    PVOID info = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, bufSize);
    PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES pPrivileges = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)info;
    
    // Get token information include priveleges id
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, pPrivileges, bufSize, &bufSize);
    LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES* luid = pPrivileges->Privileges;
    
    // Allocate the space for privilege name
    TCHAR name_buffer[64];
    DWORD dwNameLen = sizeof(name_buffer);
    
    // Output privileges
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < pPrivileges->PrivilegeCount; i++) {
    
        LookupPrivilegeName(NULL, &(pPrivileges->Privileges[i].Luid), name_buffer, &dwNameLen);
    
        wcout << name_buffer << '\t' << pPrivileges->Privileges[i].Attributes << '\n';
    
        wcout << pPrivileges->Privileges[i].Luid.HighPart << pPrivileges->Privileges[i].Luid.LowPart << '\n';
    
    }

}
```

My output:

Input PID:
8564

- SeShutdownPrivilege     0
- LUID:019
- SeShutdownPrivilege     3
- LUID:023
- SeUndockPrivilege       0
- LUID:025
- SeUndockPrivilege       0
- LUID:033
- SeTimeZonePrivilege     0
- LUID:034

Whoami outptut:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| SeShutdownPrivilege | Disabled |
| SeChangeNotifyPrivilege | Enabled |
| SeUndockPrivilege | Disabled |
| SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege | Disabled |
| SeTimeZonePrivilege | Disabled |

As you can see SeChangeNotifyPrivilege that is enabled displayed like SeShutdownPrivilege and I cant understand why. Can it be a trouble with a heap and I need clean buffer each iteration of the loop?

P.S
I know that I get a primal token for process and whoami output access token, but for this process, the primal token is completely inherited from the access token.

Comment: because you pass wrong value in `dwNameLen`. it must be `_countof(name_buffer)` before every call to `LookupPrivilegeName` (not once before loop)

Comment: A reasonable remark, but it doesnt help with problem just reduces space allocated in memory (I have the same output).

Comment: no, you dont understand. your code is wrong now. you not check return value of `LookupPrivilegeName` and it fail. again - you wrong init `dwNameLen`. and better use `LsaLookupPrivilegeName`

Comment: also use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`, not `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`

Comment: Thx, you really help me, I added _count of(name_buffer) in loop and it works now. But why does this happen? I thought LookupPrivilegeName writes data to the same memory location with the same address, why does it crashes every time after one iteration?

Comment: LookupPrivilegeName modify dwNameLen after call. and set actual length of name. so if you query longer name than - call fail. and again - not use LookupPrivilegeName at all. use LsaLookupPrivilegeName

Comment: @RbMm you wrote _"and better use `LsaLookupPrivilegeName`"_. I couldn't find any `LsaLookupPrivilegeName` function...

Comment: @Jabberwocky - it declared in *um\ntlsa.h* . the *LookupPrivilegeName* call *LsaOpenPolicy*, *LsaLookupPrivilegeName*, ( *LsaFreeMemory* 2 time) and *LsaClose*. if we need do multiple calls for query luid - better only once call `LsaOpenPolicy` before loop and `LsaClose` after loop.

Comment: demo code - https://gist.github.com/rbmm/9a64857ff9d1f80d996c6aff6295459c

Comment: @RbMm Your demo code deserves an answer.